# Maven dependencies in Eclipse for enterprise project

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I have two components with own maven dependencies combined into one enterprise project. It is built/deployed/run normally, but Eclipse can't resolve maven dependencies. Project is turned to be maven, and "use maven dependency management" option is enabled. However Eclipse gives me compilation errors. 
What should I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was about the version of m2eclipse plugin.
Good plugin can be downloaded here:
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/archives/m2e-0.10.2.20100623-1649/

Answer (score 0):

Check if the maven dependencies are included in the classpath and add if it is not there.

```
Right click on project -> Properties -> Build Path -> Libraries -> 
Add Library -> Maven Managed Dependencies
```

After that you may also need to

```
Select Project -> From top menu -> Project -> Clean and build if auto build is not enabled
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @fmucar , should I add each library one by one (I have lots of them:))?

Comment: no, see above, i have edited it. You will only need to add maven managed dependencies and the rest will be taken care of by eclipse-maven

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much, @fmucar , I'll try it tomorrow in the morning.

Comment: I have Maven Classpath Container already added to the Libraries.If I choose "Add Library" I see only "Maven Classpath Container Page" which is actually disabled (doesn't react on my actions).What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW (if it's important) I have Eclipse Helios and m2eclipse plugin installed. All the Maven dependencies were ok when I had single web-project. Eclipse lost dependencies when I splitted project into separated web and ejb parts, and combined this parts into one enterprise project.